# How do I run a not-so-old PC game on windows 10?

Tags: gaming, emulator

There is an old PC game called SubTerra ( [link](http://crystalshard.net/?g=2) ). It used to run perfectly on Windows XP but fails to do so in Windows 10. Compatibility troubleshooter also didn’t help. DOSbox cannot emulate this game. Any suggestions as to how to run this game smoothly on Windows 10 ?

Comment: if you are installing older software in windows 10 then you will get too many driver and supported file issues. My suggestion is to deploy oracle virtual box(free :-)) in the same machine and run xp in that and continue gaming with out any issues

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a circuitous route, but you could try installing Linux in a virtual machine with [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/). Some old Windows programs run better under Wine than they do on Windows 10. VirtualBox's Seamless Mode can (kind of) integrate the virtual machine's windows with your Windows desktop. Linux Mint would be one of the easiest distributions to set up.

Or, as @vembutech noted, you may be able to run an older version of Windows in a virtual machine (*if* you have access to a legal copy).